# How to use separate block caches for secure and unsecure shop access in Magento?

Tags: magento

I use the Magento block cache for the top navigation block. The problem is the block has to generate some urls for files in the skin directory that cannot be put into css files as the file names depend on category model data.

Now when I open magento using a secure connection (https://) the navigation block is fetched from the cache and is sent to the browser but with the http:// urls resulting in a warning in most browsers about unsecure elements on the page.

I'd like the have separat caches for secure and unsecure connections. The navigation block extends the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` and therefore has the following cache configuration:

```
    $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime'    => false,
        'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG, Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::CACHE_TAG),
    ));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm simpler than I thought...

I tried overriding the method `getCacheKey()` by appending a flag with the current security status but at first this was no success but after several cache purges this seems to work now:

```
public function getCacheKey()
{
    $key = parent::getCacheKey();
    $key .= Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure() ? '_S' : '_U';

    return $key;
}
```

Comment: There's an example of this in the core Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer in v1.3.2.4 as well:
    `/**
     * Retrieve Key for caching block content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCacheKey()
    {
        return 'PAGE_FOOTER_' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
            . '_' . (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
            . '_' . Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName()
            . '_' . Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template');
    }`